# Compiled Query in LINQ error?

Tags: c#, linq

I am getting the error below and I am not sure the syntax is correct for multiple criteria in the LINQ query.
My code thus far,

```
static class MyQuery
    {
        private static Func<DatabaseDataContext, IQueryable<Staff_Time_TBL>>
                     queryFor =
                     CompiledQuery.Compile((DatabaseDataContext db, DateTime dDate) =>
                     db.Staff_Time_TBLs.Where(a => a.Date_Data == dDate &&
                     a.Time_Data_1 == null && a.Time_Data_2 == null).FirstOrDefault());        
    }
```

- `DatabaseDataContext` is the name of the LINQ to SQL class.
- `Staff_Time_TBL` is the table to get data from.

This is the error,

> Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Func
>   (Example3.DatabaseDataContext, System.DateTime,
>   Example3.Staff_Time_TBL)' to 'System.Func
>   (Example3.DatabaseDataContext,
>   System.Linq.IQueryable(Example3.Staff_Time_TBL))'

I would post all my attempts at getting this right ,but would clutter the post.

Used this as research to get to this point.

- [How to: Store and Reuse Queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399335(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Compiled Queries (LINQ to Entities)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896297(v=vs.100).aspx)
- [How to improve your LINQ query performance by 5 X times?](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38174/How-to-improve-your-LINQ-query-performance-by-X)
- [Compiled Queries in LINQ](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dhananjaycoder/compiled-queries-in-linq/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've defined your field as:

```
Func<DatabaseDataContext, IQueryable<Staff_Time_TBL>>
```

Which has the equivelant method signature:

```
public IQueryable<Staff_Time_TBL> SomeMethod(DatabaseDataContext db)
{
    ...
}
```

But look at what you're passing it:

```
(DatabaseDataContext db, DateTime dDate) =>
    db.Staff_Time_TBLs.Where(a => a.Date_Data == dDate &&
    a.Time_Data_1 == null && a.Time_Data_2 == null)
    .FirstOrDefault()
```

With the equivelant method:

```
public Staff_Time_TBL SomeMethod(DatabaseDataContext db, DateTime dDate)
{
    return 
        db.Staff_Time_TBLs
        .Where(a => a.Date_Data == dDate && a.Time_Data_1 == null && a.Time_Data_2 == null)
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

This has two arguments, not one. You're also executing `.FirstOrDefault()`, which means you're returning `Staff_Time_TBL` - not `IQueryable<Staff_Time_TBL>`

Without knowing *exactly* what you're trying to do, it's likely you should re-write the field as:

```
private static Func<DatabaseDataContext, DateTime, Staff_Time_TBL>
    queryFor =
    CompiledQuery.Compile((DatabaseDataContext db, DateTime dDate) =>
    db.Staff_Time_TBLs.Where(a => a.Date_Data == dDate &&
    a.Time_Data_1 == null && a.Time_Data_2 == null).FirstOrDefault());
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the awesome answer and the explanation. (Yes that works for me BTW) A quick question for me to further understand this.  Does that mean the `Staff_Time_TBL` table in this line of code `Func<DatabaseDataContext, DateTime, Staff_Time_TBL>` is in fact an IQueryable?

Comment: @KyloRen No, it's a single object. When you call `FirstOrDefault()`, you are no longer using an `IQueryable<>` - because a single object is not a queryable set.

Comment: So if you were to use `Tolist` or something like that it would? Thanks for the help.

Comment: @KyloRen `ToList()` would give you an `IEnumerable`, but it would materialize the result, so it would no longer be `IQueryable`. If you want `IQueryable`, simply remove `.FirstOrDefault()` - that's all

Comment: Ahh I see now. Thanks so much for the help, I spent days on this.